# Case when expression from Case When Result

Tags: sql-server, case

I need to write a case when expression from the results of a previous case when expression.

```
 case 
    when state = 'nj' and date >= '2018-01-01' then 'new'
    else 'existing' 
end as 'new or existing'

case
    when state = 'nj' and 'new or existing' = 'existing' and date <= '2017-12-31' 
       then 'eligible'
       else 'next time' 
end as 'eligibility'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You'll either need to rewrite the case over again or move the result of it into a subquery.  You can't use the alias in the same select statement like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the nested `case when` can make it.

```
(case
    when state='nj' and 
    (
    case 
        when date < '2018-01-01' then 'existing'
    end 
    )='existing' and date <= '2017-12-31' then 'eligible'
else 'next time' 
end
) as 'eligibility'
```

Clear up your logic, I think you just need this.

```
(case
    when state='nj' and date <= '2017-12-31' then 'eligible'
else 'next time' 
end
) as 'eligibility'
```

You can also use `IIF` to make it.

```
IIF(state = 'nj' AND IIF(date < '2018-01-01','existing','new') ='existing' and date <= '2017-12-31' , 'eligible','next time') as 'eligibility'
```

[IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I appreciate the response @d-shih however I must apologize.  I need result set of 'new or existing' to be a column (I'll just call it 'new or existing') and based off of it would be second case when expression
        case when 'new or existing'='existing' and date <='2017-12-31' then 'eligible' else 'next time' end as 'eligibility'

Comment: Have you tried to write a subquery to make first `CASE WHEN`, then outer query use another `CASE WHEN` @MichaelCallirgos

Comment: Yes this is what I am attempting to do right now.  I have tried multiple ways with no success as of yet.